# Disable text selection, copy, cut and paste in Google forms through Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-forms

I'm trying to disable text selection, copy, cut and paste in Google Forms. This is not possible by default in Google Forms but you can add this functionality through Google Apps Script by calling a JavaScript function.

I am not familiar with JavaScript. I opened the apps script editor and found a single file `Code.gs`. I looked around the internet and found a JavaScript function to disable select which I pasted in the `Code.gs` file:

```
    function disableSelect(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
    }
```

But when I run the file, it prompts the error: `Typerror: Cannot read property 'preventdefault' of undefined`. What am I doing wrong and how can I implement the rest of the functionalities?

Comment: I cannot understand about the relationship between the error of `Cannot read property 'preventdefault' of undefined` and the script in your question. Can you provide the script and the detail flow for replicating your current issue?

Comment: When you say you want to disable copy etc. - do you mean copying the whole form as a file on your Drive or the contents of the form (the questions)? In both cases the procedure would be more complicated than googling a line of code. Please mind that `event.preventDefault():` is a Javascript method that works only client-side (and does something very different from what you expect). Whilst Apps Script is based on Javascript,you cannot directly use all Javascript methods in it, since it runs serverside. If you are interested in learning it - see [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this jQuery to stop cut, copy, and paste in any html document. Drop any option you want if necessary in bind function.

Add this code segment,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Above code normally added in head tag of our document

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
          $('body').bind('cut copy paste', function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
</script>
```

**Above code can be add to body tag of our document or separate js file.